# Sending an Email Using Commons-Email to Gmail

Tags: java, email, apache-commons-email

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
String authuser = "......@gmail.com";
String authpwd = "*******";
// Very Important, Don't use email.setAuthentication()
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(authuser, authpwd));
email.setDebug(true); // true if you want to debug
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");

email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.debug", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
email.setFrom("........@gmail.com", "SenderName");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail?");
email.addTo(".............@gmail.com", "ToName");
email.send();
```

and it gives the following exception

```
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
```

Comment: Can you post the entire exception stack trace? The cause of the exception is probably listed somewhere in it. The exception is generic. It could be a simple authentication failure or it could be something else. cheers

Answer (score 19):

The Commons Email user guide has an example for Gmail using SSL.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html

**SSL/TLS (Port 465)** -> email.setSSLOnConnect(true);

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

**STARTTLS (Port 587)** -> email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

Comment: I am getting class javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. g66sm11757390ywh.8 - gsmtp
exception. But, I updated code same as your code.

Answer (score 14):

This does work for me

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
String authuser = "...@gmail.com";
String authpwd = "xxxx";
email.setSmtpPort(587);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(authuser, authpwd));
email.setDebug(true);
email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.debug", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.port", "587");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.port", "587");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.class",   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
email.setFrom("........@gmail.com", "SenderName");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail?");
email.addTo("xxxx@gmail.com", "ToName");
email.setTLS(true);
email.send();
```

Comment: this code works for me (just need to remove email.setTLS(true))- Thanks jitter

Answer (score 10):

Don't you need to [tell Commons Email that you're sending a TLS email](http://commons.apache.org/email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html#setTLS%28boolean%29):

```
email.setTLS(true);
```

prior to your call to email.send()?

I'm not sure if this will fix what ails you, since I'm not sure whether you're experiencing a problem connecting to smtp.gmail.com:465 or successfully sending to it (the error message/exception is ambiguous as you've presented it), but it's definitely something that's missing so far as I can tell.

Comment: This has been deprecated since 1.3, use `setStartTLSEnabled()` instead

Comment: to use port 587
either set this: email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use TLS use port 587 and starttls:

```
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
// or call this:
email.setStartTLSEnabled().
// and set the port to 587
email.setSmtpPort(smtpPort);
```

If you want to use port 465 then do not set this true but call below functions:

```
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setSslSmptPort("465");
// or can set below but remember it is not "smtps" it is "smtp" and port nmber should be 465.

email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable google [Less secure app access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).