# Commons email example hanging on send()

Tags: java, email, apache-commons-email

I'm trying to get [this example](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html) for the Apache Commons email library to work.  Here is my code:

```
    SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();      
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.setSmtpPort(465);
    email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username@gmail.com", "password"));     
    email.setTLS(true); 
    try {
        email.setFrom("username@gmail.com");
        email.setSubject("TestMail");
        email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
        email.addTo("username@gmail.com");
        System.out.println("Sending...");
        email.send();
        System.out.println("Email sent!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Email not sent!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As you can see it's basically unchanged from the example, except I have to use port 465 instead of 587 because 587 causes a `Connection refused` exception (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783710/sending-an-email-using-commons-email-to-gmail)).  Now this code is hanging on the `email.send()` line.  The only output I get is:

```
Sending...
```

But no exceptions are thrown. Do I need to open a port in my firewall?  (I might not be able to do that as I'm trying to do this from work).  Thanks!

### Edit

After a long time I get this exception:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
...
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465, response: -1
```

Comment: If you try to telnet from the command line, can you?

$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 // If you're running linux, no problem, with windows, you may need to add the telnet program, just go to the control panel and add it in the windows components.

Comment: I cannot.  telnet hangs for a while and then fails silently.  However, see my edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edits and answer to my comment, you shouldn't look for your problems in Java code, but in the firewall or your network configuration.

Comment: Indeed, there's a mail relay server I need to use, TPS reports to fill out, etc etc.  I was really hoping to learn something here too D:.  Oh well, have some reputation, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following (because you are using SSL)

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.timeout" , "10000");
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout" , "10000");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Comment: Also it is hanged because you didn't set the timeout properties